# jqgrid guriddo - how to get all data after processed

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to return all data from my jqgrid??

This work great but I only get clear data.

```
this.element.jqGrid('getRowData')
```

For example I have column approved with settings:

```
   {
        editoptions: {value: "t:Yes;f:No;null:No"},
        value: "t:Yes;f:No;null:No",
        edittype: "select",
        formatter: "select",
        index: "approved",
        label: "Approved",
        name: "approved",
        resizable: false,
        search: false
    }
```

When I use "getRowData" I get value for this column "f" but I need "No".

I looked into documentation and I didnt find method which gave me data after processed only clear data.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is your data local or comes from the server? Do you have set a parameter loadonce to true?

Comment: Data comes from server and loadonce is false. Is it problem?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data comes from the server only and you want to get the text from select you will need to define your own custom unformat function. like this:

```
{
        editoptions: {value: "t:Yes;f:No;null:No"},
        value: "t:Yes;f:No;null:No",
        edittype: "select",
        formatter: "select",
        unformat : function( cellval, options, cell) {
            return cellval;
        },
        index: "approved",
        label: "Approved",
        name: "approved",
        resizable: false,
        search: false
    }
```

and use the getRowData as of your code

in case of loadonce true or local datatype parameter you will nedd to query the data parameter

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', data);
```

or to use the second parameter in getRowData to return tha data array

```
this.element.jqGrid('getRowData', true);
```

Comment: @user1951618 Thank you. Glad to help.